Lemma Orthogonality Kreyszig: characterization of the projection onto a subspace.
In the Lemma Ortogonality in Kreyszig's book it is proven that if $Y$ is a subspace of an Hilbert space $H$ then holds that  $$y=P_Y(x)\ \implies x-y\in Y^\perp $$
where $P_Y(x)$ denotes the projection of $x\in H$ on $Y$.

Is the vice versa true?
That is if $y\in Y$ then it is true or false that$$x-y\in Y^\perp \implies y=P_Y(x)$$

For me the answer is yes. Now I write my motivation: results for $z\in Y$ that $$\lVert x-z \rVert^2 =\lVert(x-y)-(z-y) \rVert^2=\lVert x-y \rVert^2-2\Re\langle x-y, z-y\rangle+\lVert z-y \rVert^2.$$ Since $z-y\in Y$ results that $\Re\langle x-y, z-y\rangle=0$. Then we have that $$\lVert x-y\rVert^2- \lVert x-z\rVert^2=-\lVert z-y\rVert^2 \le 0\quad \forall z\in Y.$$ Therefore,
$$\lVert x-y \rVert\le \inf_{z\in Y} \lVert x-z\rVert.$$ On the other hand, since $y\in Y$ we have that $$\lVert x-y\rVert\ge \inf_{z\in Y} \lVert x-z\rVert.$$ Thus, $$\lVert x-y\rVert= \inf_{z\in Y} \lVert x-z\rVert$$ and this implis that $y=P_Y(x)$.

Is this explanation correct? Thanks!


Yes it is correct
